# Errata for Wooldridge graduate econometrics book

Tags: econometrics, applied-econometrics

Does anyone know where I can find an errata to the 2nd edition (2010) of «[Econometric Analysis of Cross-Section and Panel Data](https://mitpress.mit.edu/books/econometric-analysis-cross-section-and-panel-data)» by Wooldridge? I've tried the accompanying website, but I could not find it.

Any help would be appreciated

Comment: I added a date (to avoid any confusion) and a link. For those interested in the errata of the 2nd printing of the 1st edition (2003). [Here it is](ftp://ftpeagle.bc.edu/pub/user/gottscha/helen/Courses/Econometrics/PhDEconometrics/2004fall/Wooldridge%20Downloads/errata2.pdf).

Answer (score 1):

I know I've referenced that text before so I ran a quick search. Here's the instructor's solution manual.

[Wooldridge Instructor Edition - Cross Section & Panel](https://www.dropbox.com/s/319ic47d502jll9/Archive%201.zip?dl=0)